# How to prevent ASP.NET 4.0 URL Reroute from breaking jQuery scripts

Tags: .net, asp.net, url, url-rewriting

I've been using the ASP.NET WebForms 4.0 URL Rerouting for some time now and it's been great with one exception.

It's been breaking the jQuery scripts I add by breaking the images that are included in the script. Previously I've circumvented this by simply editing the .js files and putting full path to images in there but now I am trying to add the Wymeditor and it's not that simple anymore.

I am trying to define a rule in Global.asax that would disable routing for all my .js files in a specified folder. My wymeditor is in **scripts/wymeditor**. The forms resides in **someaddress/blog/new-post** which routes to AddNewPost.aspx. I tried doing

```
routes.Ignore("{*alljs}", new {alljs=@".*\.js(/.*)?"});
```

But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about the editor or reroute, but you may use paths relative to the server root like, instead of "Folder/AnotherFolder/Myfile.js" you can use "/Folder/AnotherFolder/Myfile.js", it avoids the confusion in most scenarios, maybe it will save you too.

Comment: Nice to see it works. :) I (and believe me, lots of others) also have spent a lot of time in the past trying to solve this simple thing.